# HTML table using MySQLi and PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a table connected to my database so I can use the information in that database.

I think I'm on the right way, but currently the table only displays the first row. Anyone got any ideas on what's going on?

```
         <table id="fairtable">
            <tr>
                <td>Fair Name</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Are we there?</td>
                <td>Website</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT `name`,`date`,`present`,`website` FROM `dates`";
            $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['present'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $rowitem['website'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: try `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: You should also add some error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP can use  `mysqli_fetch_array` itself but he needs to iterate it with `while` instead of `foreach` i.e., _while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is because you have not opened your HTML table tags correctly, its an easy thing to overlook. Also loop the result set inside a white statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT `name`,`date`,`present`,`website` FROM `dates`";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "<table>"; //begin table tag...
//you can add thead tag here if you want your table to have column headers
 while($rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowitem['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowitem['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowitem['present'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowitem['website'] . "</td>";*/
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; //end table tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets only one row from table, you need loop your results.
Try this code:

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
  //do smth
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This is just the same as Fred-ii suggested. You shall consider explaining the answer with little more information

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen if I was wrong about suggesting the OP to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` you should have said: *"Nah Fred, that won't work buddy"* ;-) I'll be glad to delete my comment about it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes i can say that, but the mistake is mainly because of `foreach` which should be as `while`  which i want @mcklayin to explain it. I will convey you hereafter for sure :) Thanks for being kind :)